# Can't switch to full screen apps or evoke Mission Control after sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, mission-control, fullscreen, expose

Occasionally when I am working and put my MacBook to sleep, when I wake it up again, I am unable to switch to apps that I have had open in full screen. Similarly, if I open an app after sleep, switch to full screen mode and then command-tab to another application, I cannot return the full screen app.

Mission Control ceases to operate and gestures for switching (multi-finger swipes up to Exposé and to the side for screen switching) also fail.

The only fix I have found is a full restart.

My setup is as follows:

- MacBook Pro 15" Retina Early 2013
- 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB RAM
- OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 (14E17e)
- Built-in screen and external monitor
- Apple Magic Trackpad (issue also present with built-in trackpad)

The issue presents itself sporadically and has been present for at least the last few Yosemite releases.

Any help would be very well received :-)

Comment: You are using an unreleased OS. You may need to wait for a fix.

Comment: As mentioned **"... has been present for at least the last few Yosemite releases"**

Comment: It's 2018 im on 10.13.1 and it's still happening. `killall Dock` worked!

Comment: And apparently in Feb 2022, with MacOS 12 Monterey, this is still a problem...

Answer (score 4):

I get the same symptoms/failure.  The following Terminal command fixes it for me:

*killall Dock*

But before you do that, run *killall -s Dock* to make sure it's only going to directly kill the one "Dock" process. Dock will restart and then mission control is working again - for me anyway. You can verify that the restart happened by looking at the process ID of "Dock" after the restart. Hope this helps!

Comment: solved it for me

Comment: Force quitting the Dock in Activity Monitor also seems to work.